# Google Maps API v2 shows an empty map

Tags: android, google-maps, key

Im trying to make Google Maps to be shown but I cant understand what is wrong. To be more specific I did tried 3 different SHA1 keys: 1 from debug keystore and 2 other new generated keys, I did generated different API keys and still no map. Im using this program http://writecodeeasy.blogspot.ro/2013/01/androidtutorial-gmaps.html.

Comment: you need md5 key,not sha1 key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you Used "-v" when getting generated MD5 key like Below?

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes I did and I received SHA1. MD5 is not anymore so I cant use MD5. But still as I read other forums I still understand that the problem is the API key not the program or something missing. Thx for reply. I still try to make it work but nothing...

Comment: Now I made it work but I think is goodle maps v1, for v2 I dont know what to do with blank map. Thanks for reply.